# activerecord not saving a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two classes like this

```
class ReducaoZ < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'reducaoz'   
  has_many :aliquotas, foreign_key: 'reducaoz_id', class_name: 'Aliquota', dependent: :delete_all
end


class Aliquota < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'aliquota'

  belongs_to :reducaoz, class_name: 'ReducaoZ'
end
```

in a certain time, I add an `Aliquota` to a `ReudcaoZ`

```
aliquota = reucao.aliquotas.build
aliquota.basecalculo = aliquota.valor
# other stuff
red.aliquotas << aliquota
```

and when I try to save the record, seems like the `aliquota` is missing his reference to `reducaoz`

this is the SQL

```
  SQL (23.4ms)  INSERT INTO "aliquota" ("aliquota", "basecalculo", "valor") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["aliquota", "0300"], ["basecalculo", "0.0"], ["valor", "0.0"]]
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reducaoz_id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "aliquota" ("aliquota", "basecalculo", "valor") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "reducaoz_id" violates not-null constraint
```

am I missing something?

Comment: yeah aliquota.reducaoz = an_instance_of_reducaoz ...

Comment: I don't think I need this when using `reducao.aliquota.build`. I have some other models and I'm using this `build` and it's working fine. But I tried this and still didn't worked

Comment: The `class_name` of your `foreign_key` should be `'Reducaoz'` not `'Aliquota'`

Comment: Is your `reucao` persisted ?

Comment: @Pavan Now, when I try to `reducao.aliquotas.build` it gives a `Reducaoz` instance! @Sparda, not yet...I'm persisting the `reducao` at that point

Comment: have to tried giving it the primary key `belongs_to :reducaoz, class_name: 'ReducaoZ', primary_key: 'reducaoz_id` this seems like it should work for you. Generally if I have to reference classes with odd naming conventions I will specify both the `primary` and `foreign` keys explicitly even if they are implied to avoid confusion.

Comment: @engineersmnky just did it. no success

Comment: @LuizE. how many changes have you implemented at this point? have you rolled everything back to the original point as is listed above?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, I'm always rolling back hahahaha damn :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that it does not know what the primary key in `Aliquota` is for linking the 2 classes. try this.

```
class ReducaoZ < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'reducaoz'   
  has_many :aliquotas, primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'reducaoz_id', class_name: 'Aliquota', dependent: :delete_all
end


class Aliquota < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'aliquota'

  belongs_to :reducaoz, class_name: 'ReducaoZ', primary_key: 'reducaoz_id', foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

Generally if I have to specify `class_name` I will explicitly set the `primary` and `foreign` keys as well for clarity.

from your comment

```
json_data.aliquotas_list.each_with_index do |al, index|
  aliquota = reducao.aliquotas.build
  # populate aliquota
  red.aliquotas << aliquota
end
red.save!
```

what is `red`?

where is `reducao` defined?

Also is the piped `al` already a formatted `Aliquota`?

Otherwise I need a bit more code since I cannot see the objects being referenced.

**Edit** -After further clarification in comment

```
reducao = ReducaoZ.new
if reducao.save
  json_data.aliquotas_list.each_with_index do |al, index|
    aliquota = reducao.aliquotas.build
    # populate aliquota
    aliquota.save
  end
end
```

Save `reducao` first and if it passes validation then `build` the `aliquota`(s) on save they will immediately be associated because of the `build` method so no need to resave `reducao`.

Comment: This didn't worked too.. this gist shows exactly what I'm doing https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/880cc9e2e4fb7da8b918

Comment: 1) red is reducao. I forgot to change the name to post here. 2) reducao is defined on the beggining of the class, like `reducao = ReducaoZ.new`. 3) al is not a formatted `Aliquota` so that, I have to set field by field

Comment: @LuizE. If ReducaoZ is `new` and unsaved then it has no `id` thus no `id` is populated into the `aliquotas` I have edited my answer with a brief version of how to handle.

Comment: I tried to save `reducao` before the `json_data.aliquotas_list.each_with_index do |al, index|` with no success. The only workaround that I found was to save and reload the `ReducaoZ` before build the aliquotas. Ugly, I know

Comment: By reload, I mean `ReducaoZ.last` :-(

Comment: @LuizE. your are aware `reload` is a method to reload an object just call `reducao.reload`

Comment: @LuizE. you could also use `save!` which will modify the receiver in place. I would however advise against this in most cases as `save!` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` exception if it fails where as `save` just returns a `boolean` based on validity of the object. You could also consider a [Transaction Block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) as they seem to fit your needs. A transaction block in essence says do all of these things and if any of them fail rollback the db.

Comment: I'm catching any error on `save` on the superclass, so, use `save!` isn't a problem. The transaction block seems nice too. I'll try to use too. Thanks a lot, @engineersmnky